# How to change gnome-terminal title in Ubuntu 10

Tags: ubuntu, tabs, title, gnome-terminal

I've tried setting my **PROMPT_COMMAND** variable:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;"myWindowTitle"\007"'
```

but something changes my tab (or the whole terminal title) to '**user@hostname:/current/path**', thus

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;"myWindowTitle"\007" && sleep 3'
```

changes title for 3 second only :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PROMPT_COMMAND` is issued before a prompt is set based on the `PS1` variable. Probably you have some character sequence in PS1 which sets your windows title. You may invoke `unset PS1` or set it to some other value:

```
export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

Alternatively you can set window title in your PS1 variable:

```
export PS1='\[\e]0;myWindowTitle\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$'
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu the .bashrc file has some code that adds text to the PS1 variable. This extra text changes the title after you set it with the --title option. Just comment it.

```
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than do:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;myWindowTitle\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$'
```

Try using a variable and setting this in your .bashrc:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;$WT\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$'
```

Then you can simply do this to change the window title at the prompt by:

```
WT="my new window title"
```

If you like, you can include the path in the window title in your .bashrc:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;$WT: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$'
```

BTW, I don't think you need to "export" PS1.

Comment: slight nuance, if you put a ```\``` in front of ```$WT```, then you can change the WT variable 'in live', and it will immediately change your terminal title :-)

Answer (score 0):

Taking [justingordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009332/justingordon)'s answer, and running with it, find the second occurrence of PS1 set in bashrc, which looks like this:

```
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;\${TITLE} ${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

change to:

```
export TITLE=bash
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;\${TITLE} ${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

Now, the title will be prefixed with the variable `TITLE`. Just change the value of `TITLE` in your terminal, eg `TITLE=ec2` and the title will immediately change :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu add a function to set the title on your `.bashrc` by adding the lines:

```
settitle () {
  export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
  echo -ne '\033]0;'"$1"'\a'
}
```

Then simply use:

```
settitle FooBar
```

to set the title to e.g. `FooBar`:
[image]
If you have multiple tabs, this will set the title of the current tab. The title of the window is at all times that of the currently selected tab.
[image]